# Отставание state в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]возникла проблема:

Я делаю конвертер валют на React + redux
Я получаю Rub input, передаю его в редакс, умножаю на курс доллара и передаю в Currency input, но туда приходит старое значение инпута
никто не знает как исправить ошибку?

Кода много,  решил прикрепить гитхаб:
https://github.com/maksimcoder/int_react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была здесь:

```
case "RUB_INPUT":
      console.log("reducer", action.value);
      return {
        ...state,
        rubInputNum: action.value,
        curInputNum: +action.value, // <--- 
      };
```

`state.rubInputNum` это старое значение

Лучше подключать девТулз, чтобы видеть весь Редакс:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers";

import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools());

export default store;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, есть еще вопрос.
Не могу понять как сделать обновление курса при смене валюты, можете подсказать?